# DeadObjectException when dismissing Dialog in API 23

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-6.0-marshmallow

I just upgraded my project to API 23 and I'm getting an error on code that always worked before. The crash occurs when I call `dialog.dismiss()` in the Spinner listener below. It does not crash if I do not call `dismiss` in this area.

```
void showWeekViewOptionsDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_weekview_options, null);

    final MaterialSpinnerCallsSameItemSelected spinner = (MaterialSpinnerCallsSameItemSelected) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_weekview_days);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dayListAdapter;

    ArrayList<Integer> dayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    dayList.add(2);
    dayList.add(3);

    dayListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(getActivity(), R.layout.my_spinner_item, dayList);
    dayListAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dayListAdapter);

    spinner.setSelection(dayListAdapter.getPosition(mWeekViewType));

    b.setView(view);
    final AlertDialog dialog = b.create();
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedEvenIfUnchangedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            dialog.dismiss();  // crashes here!
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Below is the logcat output. I don't know what it means by **Abandoned Buffer Queue** or the **DeadObjectException**.  From my research, it looks like maybe an object is being referenced from a dead process? I don't understand why that would be the case or why this only occurs in Marshmallow. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
01-06 17:53:45.791 4436-4485/com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9c359200
01-06 17:53:46.066 1278-1303/system_process W/WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{df5d861 u0 PopupWindow:ac39394} from container Window{d72786b u0 com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication/com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication.Activity_Main}
01-06 17:53:46.087 941-1963/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [PopupWindow:ac39394] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
01-06 17:53:46.089 941-941/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
01-06 17:53:46.090 4436-4485/com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication E/EGL_emulation: tid 4485: swapBuffers(322): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
01-06 17:53:46.090 4436-4485/com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication A/OpenGLRenderer: Encountered EGL error 12291 EGL_BAD_ALLOC during rendering
01-06 17:53:46.090 4436-4485/com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4485 (RenderThread)
01-06 17:53:46.208 949-949/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-06 17:53:46.208 949-949/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:6.0/MASTER/2497369:userdebug/test-keys'
01-06 17:53:46.208 949-949/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
01-06 17:53:46.208 949-949/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
01-06 17:53:46.208 949-949/? A/DEBUG: pid: 4436, tid: 4485, name: RenderThread  >>> com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication <<<
01-06 17:53:46.208 949-949/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-06 17:53:46.210 949-949/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'Encountered EGL error 12291 EGL_BAD_ALLOC during rendering'
01-06 17:53:46.211 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 00001154  ecx 00001185  edx 00000006
01-06 17:53:46.211 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     esi a2cbf980  edi 0000000b
01-06 17:53:46.211 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000077  xss 0000007b
01-06 17:53:46.211 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     eip b7304696  ebp 00001185  esp a2cbf150  flags 00200202
01-06 17:53:46.211 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00083696  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+22)
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000815e8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+70)
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00027205  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+36)
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000209e4  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+80)
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000cbc3  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+128)
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00023759  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0001e866  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000216ef  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00027137  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+151)
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00014aac  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+418)
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0006bfee  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+98)
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 000141cf  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+122)
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00080a93  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+56)
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00021952  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+25)
01-06 17:53:46.212 949-949/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 000170b6  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
01-06 17:53:46.282 949-949/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
01-06 17:53:46.282 1278-1298/system_process I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
01-06 17:53:46.303 1278-8703/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication/.Activity_Main
01-06 17:53:46.309 955-955/? I/Zygote: Process 4436 exited due to signal (6)
01-06 17:53:46.319 1278-1320/system_process W/InputDispatcher: channel 'bbdfcc6 com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication/com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication.Activity_Main (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
01-06 17:53:46.319 1278-1320/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'bbdfcc6 com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication/com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication.Activity_Main (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-06 17:53:46.323 1278-1820/system_process D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 3
01-06 17:53:46.391 941-941/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 941: eglCreateSyncKHR(1294): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
01-06 17:53:46.437 1278-1820/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{bbdfcc6 u0 com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication/com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication.Activity_Main}
01-06 17:53:46.437 1278-1820/system_process W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'bbdfcc6 com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication/com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication.Activity_Main (server)'
01-06 17:53:46.437 1278-8703/system_process W/ActivityManager: Exception thrown during pause
                                                               android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                                   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:727)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:867)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2907)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2763)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2755)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11971)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11867)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12556)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:12063)
                                                                   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
01-06 17:53:46.441 1278-1290/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.NSouthDomain.NSouthApplication (pid 4436) has died
01-06 17:53:46.549 1278-3883/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-06 17:53:46.584 1595-1904/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-06 17:53:46.584 1595-1904/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa21efb80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-06 17:53:46.607 1278-3883/system_process W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-06 17:53:46.607 1278-3883/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9dba5180, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-06 17:53:47.139 1595-1904/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: em, destroying layer...
01-06 17:53:47.143 1278-1303/system_process W/WindowAnimator: Failed to dispatch window animation state change.
                                                              android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                                  at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.onAnimationStopped(IWindow.java:534)
                                                                  at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked(WindowAnimator.java:286)
                                                                  at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked(WindowAnimator.java:678)
                                                                  at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.-wrap0(WindowAnimator.java)
                                                                  at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(WindowAnimator.java:123)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:856)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                  at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
01-06 17:53:47.172 1278-1293/system_process I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-06 17:53:47.192 941-941/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
```

Comment: Two suggestion. Add null check on dialog and check if it is visible before you dismiss it.
Also post code which you have in onDestroy and onPause/onStop as well. Seems your this activity is already closed/destroyed before you are calling this.

Comment: @AnkitAwasthi, I've checked and the dialog is not null when I call `dismiss`, nor is the activity. The dialog's `isShowing()` returns true. Also, none of onPause/onStop/onDestroy are called in the activity or hosting fragment. The activity is not closed/destroyed. Thoughts?

Comment: This is interesting, can you try dialog.cancel instead of .dismiss, just to check what happens. Also just add a log line before and after the dialog.dismiss to confirm it is crashing in there only!!

Comment: @AnkitAwasthi, Yes, it's crashing on dialog.`cancel()` as well. If I add logging after `dismiss()`, the log appears. The exception is not being thrown *at* `dismiss()`. `dismiss()` is merely the last bit of my code that runs before the error occurs. The crash seems to be coming from something in the "buffer queue".

Comment: Seems you are doing some long running task in the main thread What are you doing after you call dismiss?

Comment: @AnkitAwasthi, absolutely nothing. Calling dismiss merely closes the dialog. Also, I can close the dialog with the back button and behavior is fine. Weird, huh?

Comment: It is something else, certainly not dialog. Check what is the next task you are doing after selection.

Comment: What happens if you don't set the item selected listener? Isn't the dialog being dismissed automatically? You might be trying to dismiss it twice, which fails horribly.

Comment: @EugenPechanec, the dialog is *only* dismissed by the spinner listener. The dialog has no buttons. As soon as an option is selected, the dialog is dismissed by the listener. If I comment out `dismiss` in the listener, the dialog is not dismissed and nothing happens.

Comment: Can you try >> b.setView(null); just before you `dismiss/cancel` the dialog.

Comment: @AnkitAwasthi, I did as you said and there was no change.

Comment: publish the code somewhere and let me know how to download it, can debug it more if you want.

Comment: @AnkitAwasthi, that's alright. I found a workaround. Instead of dismissing from the Spinner listener, I added a button. Now the user selects from the spinner and taps "Apply." It's one extra tap, but at least it works. Since Apply is one of the default dialog buttons, it automatically dismisses the dialog and everything is fine. Since you were helpful, you're welcome to suggest this in your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: That's cool. Why don't you write that as an answer and approve it. Also if you think I was helpful, you can upvote my current answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is a bug in M...
But i figued out a solution.
Just made a handler postDelayed call with ~ 500 ms deplay

Comment: So you dismiss the dialog with a delay of ~500ms?  Is this working? Can someone confirm?

Comment: Hi, I'm getting similar problem: when I open the BottomSheetDialog, everything is working fine. But within 1s after the BottomSheetDialog is shown app crash with the that error. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not a true answer, but I found a workaround. Instead of dismissing from the Spinner listener, I added a button. Now the user selects from the spinner and taps "Apply." It's one extra tap, but at least it works. Since Apply is one of the default dialog buttons, it automatically dismisses the dialog and everything is fine.

If anyone knows why dismissing from the Spinner listener breaks in Marshmallow, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

As par conversation in comments, you says dismiss/cancel doesn't crash the application, but it is something else after that.

Your crash logs says >>

**The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**

Check your app code and confirm that you are not doing any long running task in the main thread.

Comment: No code in my application is running after the dialog is dismissed (I've commented out what is normally run). I suspect that this has something to do with trying to dismiss from the Spinner's `onItemSelected()` listener.

Comment: Exactly that is what I am suspecting too.

Comment: Here are some tips.  
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html